# Fijar el número de cifras de un resultado Float

Tags: java

Hola muy buenas compañer@s,

Os quiero lanzar una pregunta porque ahí donde miro solo encuentro el caso para double y no para float...

Me gustaría saber cómo podria limitar el número de decimales de un resultado float, por ejemplo así #.######## (1 entero y 8 decimales).

Lo estoy intentando para esta iteración:

```
for(int j=0;j<7;j++){

                normaliz[i][j]=(datos[i][j]/datos[i][1]);
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
                x[j] = df.format(normaliz[i][j]);

                System.out.print(datos[i][j] + " ");
                fz.write(datos[i][j] + " ");

                System.out.print(normaliz[i][j] + " ");
                fw.write(normaliz[i][j] + " ");

            }
```

Lo que quiero es que el resultado normaliz[i][j] me salga en el fichero fw con un entero y 8 decimales....¿alguno sabría cómo hacerlo? ¿es obligatorio hacer casting?

Mil gracias de antemano!! Os adjunto el código entero por si es de más ayuda para entender lo que quiero hacer...

Gracias de nuevo.

```
package com.berni.filtromodif;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FiltroUnicoModifNorm3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int n=1048576;       
    //float datos[][] = new float[n][8];
    float datos[][] = new float[n][7];

    //Definimos nuevas variables:
    int Euc=0;
    int Dio=0;
    int How=0;

    int Euc_total=0;
    int Dio_total=0;
    int How_total=0;

    //float dif_euc[]= new float[n];
    //float dif_dio[]= new float[n];
    //float dif_how[]= new float[n];

    float dif_euc[][]= new float[n][2];
    float dif_dio[][]= new float[n][2];
    float dif_how[][]= new float[n][2];

    float normaliz[][] = new float[n][7];
    float x[][] = new float[n][7];

    //Scanner sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8;
    Scanner sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8;

    try {
        //sc1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 2\\berni\\f1.txt"));
        sc2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\berni\\f2.txt"));
        sc3 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\berni\\f3.txt"));
        sc4 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\berni\\f4.txt"));
        sc5 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\berni\\f5.txt"));
        sc6 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\berni\\f6.txt"));
        sc7 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\berni\\f7.txt"));
        sc8 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\berni\\f8.txt"));

        //fichero que da normalizado para cada píxel el valor de las reflectancias en cada filtro (ordenados por F8/F2/F7/F3/F6/F4/F5).
        FileWriter fw;
        fw = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\TXT Modifica3\\Orbita4B-7columnsNormalizadoR.txt"));

        //aquí escribiríamos otro fichero indicando el resultado si es eucrite/diogenite/howardite
        FileWriter fx;
        fx = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\TXT Modifica3\\ComposicionOrbita4BR.txt"));

        //fichero que indica fila a fila el resultado.
        FileWriter fy;
        fy = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\TXT Modifica3\\DiferenciasOrbita4BR.txt"));

        //fichero que da sin normalizar para cada píxel el valor de las reflectancias en cada filtro (ordenados por F8/F2/F7/F3/F6/F4/F5).
        FileWriter fz;
        fz = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4\\Imágenes modificadas 2\\TXT Modifica3\\Orbita4B-7columnsR.txt"));

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

            //if (sc1.hasNextFloat()) {
            //    datos[i][0] = sc1.nextFloat();
            //}


            if (sc8.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][0] = sc8.nextFloat();
            }


            if (sc2.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][1] = sc2.nextFloat();
            }


            if (sc7.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][2] = sc7.nextFloat();                 
            }


            if (sc3.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][3] = sc3.nextFloat();                 
            }


            if (sc6.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][4] = sc6.nextFloat();                 
            }


            if (sc4.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][5] = sc4.nextFloat();                 
            }


            if (sc5.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][6] = sc5.nextFloat();                  
            }


            //for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            for(int j=0;j<7;j++){

                normaliz[i][j]=(datos[i][j]/datos[i][1]);
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
                x[j] = df.format(normaliz[i][j]);

                System.out.print(datos[i][j] + " ");
                fz.write(datos[i][j] + " ");

                System.out.print(normaliz[i][j] + " ");
                fw.write(normaliz[i][j] + " ");

            }

            System.out.println();
            fw.write(System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.println();
            fz.write(System.lineSeparator());


           dif_euc[i][1]= (float) Math.sqrt(
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][0]-0.88126099),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][2]-1.090194054),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][3]-1.186721261),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][4]-1.080425652),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][5]-0.771797639),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][6]-0.839310604),2)); 

           dif_dio[i][1]= (float) Math.sqrt(
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][0]-0.721571227),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][2]-1.086566669),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][3]-1.04693793),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][4]-0.734598492),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][5]-0.425308693),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][6]-0.537498964),2));

           dif_how[i][1]= (int) Math.sqrt(
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][0]-0.843658437),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][2]-1.088089101),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][3]-1.09256438),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][4]-0.737644446),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][5]-0.405681366),2)+
                   Math.pow((normaliz[i][6]-0.487664752),2));

           if ((dif_euc[i][1]<dif_dio[i][1]) & (dif_euc[i][1]<dif_how[i][1])){

                    Euc=Euc+1;

                    fy.write("Euc");
                    fy.write(System.lineSeparator());
                    }


           if((dif_dio[i][1]<dif_euc[i][1]) & (dif_dio[i][1]<dif_how[i][1])){

                        Dio=Dio+1;

                        fy.write("Dio");
                        fy.write(System.lineSeparator());

                    }


            if((dif_how[i][1]<dif_euc[i][1]) & (dif_how[i][1]<dif_dio[i][1])){

                                How=How+1;

                                fy.write("How");
                                fy.write(System.lineSeparator());

                            }



            }

        fw.flush();
        fw.close();

        fz.flush();
        fz.close();

        Euc_total=(Euc*100)/(Euc+Dio+How);
        Dio_total=(Dio*100)/(Euc+Dio+How);
        How_total=(How*100)/(Euc+Dio+How);

        System.out.println(Euc);
        System.out.println(Dio);
        System.out.println(How);

        System.out.println(Euc_total);
        System.out.println(Dio_total);
        System.out.println(How_total);


        fx.write("["+"(Euc_total "+Euc_total+ "% " +") " + "(Euc "+Euc + " veces" +")"+ "]" + "\t "
                  + "["+"(Dio_total "+Dio_total+ "% " + ") " + "(Dio "+Dio + " veces"+")"+ "]" + "\t "
                  + "["+"(How_total "+How_total+ "% " + ") " + "(How "+How + " veces"+")"+ "]" );
        fx.flush();
        fx.close();

        fy.flush();
        fy.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally{
    }       



}
```

}

Comment: Yo creo que ya lo tienes hecho :). Simplemente haz lo mismo que con `x[j]`, es decir, en lugar de `fz.write(datos[i][j] + " ");` utiliza `fz.write(df.format(datos[i][j]) + " ");`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta hermano!!, pero justo en esa línea me sale error (lo que pasa que aquí no se ha mostrado)...creo que tiene que ver con el tema de que hay que hacerlo double :S

Comment: ¿Y no puedes hacer un cast `(double)`? ¿O en lugar de hacer la conversión con `double` trabajar directamente con `float`? --> Mira este link ! http://stackoverflow.com/a/14126736/1468942 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te he escrito un pequeño ejemplo:

```
public class EjemploFloatMostrarDecimales {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final float NUMERO= 18.727456787654321f;

        System.out.printf("NUMERO: %.2f\n\n", NUMERO);
        System.out.printf("NUMERO: %.5f\n", NUMERO);
        System.out.printf("NUMERO: %.0f\n", NUMERO);
    }
}
```

Esta es la salida del programa:

```
NUMERO: 18,73

NUMERO: 18,72746
NUMERO: 19
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float pi = 3.141592;
System.out.format("%.2f%n", pi); // Imprime con dos decimales : 3.14
                                 // Y %n es un salto de línea
```

Tienes un tutorial en inglés [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Para el caso de float puedes usar `%f`.

Si pones un punto y un número tras el punto se imprimen solo esos decimales; por ejemplo `%.8f` imprime solo 8 decimales de un float.

Pero el código anterior es para imprimir en pantalla y tu quieres escribir en un fichero. Para eso puedes usar [String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), que funciona como el format de System.out pero produce una cadena.

```
fz.write( String.format( "%.8f ", datos[i][j] ) );
```